# Choosing between present and past participle phrase

Tags: phrase-usage

I read in this [source](http://www.csun.edu/~bashforth/305_PDF/305_PDF_Grammar/ParticiplePhrasesAsReducedARelatives.pdf) that the past participle phrase is *used in a passive sense*, in which *the action is done to the subject described by the phrase.* It gives this example:

> Exhausted by the morning's work, I got myself a cup of coffee and sat
>   down.

But I've come across this news headline which seems to contradict that:

> Bomb explosion hit Magallanes City, killed 7 and 9 others wounded.

Here, the past participle phrase *killed 5 and 28 others wounded* is **done by the subject** *Bomb explosion*. The rule(?) above says that the subject of the sentence must not be the doer of the action in the past participle phrase. Instead, it must be **the receiver**.

So I think it must be corrected to use the present participle to describe that the doer is the subject:

> Bomb explosion hit Magallanes City, killing 7 and wounding 9 others.

Do you think the original headline is correct? How about my revision?

Comment: Headlines don't follow strict rules - they're governed more by space considerations than syntax. But I'd have expected something more like "BOMB EXPLOSION HIT MAGALLANES CITY: 7 killed, 9 wounded", where what follows the colon (or line break, or whatever) is a reduced form of "7 were killed, 9 were wounded".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, it should be noted that news[paper] headlines are usually *not* useful examples of valid grammatical constructions. Having said that, OP's example...

> Bomb explosion hit Magallanes City, killed 7 and 9 others wounded.

...is a particularly [egregious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/egregious) construction (I think it's truly *awful*). Very likely the writer wasn't what I would call a native Anglophone in the first place. The reason it's so bad is that *killed* and *wounded* are effectively being used as different "parts of speech" (the first is closer to a ***verb***: the bomb **killed** 7, but the second looks more like an ***adjectival past participle***: 9 were **wounded** [by the bomb]).

Having said that, I don't see much point in ELL discussing how *headlines* could be better phrased. OP's suggested alternative probably *is* "better", but with an article (probably ***A***) in front, it would never be considered "grammatical" in normal speech/writing.

---

OP's notion that *the subject of the sentence must not be the doer of the action in the past participle phrase* might have *some* relevance in this exact construction, but there's nothing wrong with any of...

> ***A** bomb explosion **that** hit Magallanes, **killing** 7 and **wounding** 9 others, was terrorist-inspired*.
>   and
>   ***A*** bomb explosion **that** hit Magallanes and **killed** 7 and **wounded** 9 others, was terrorist-inspired.
>   or
>   ***The*** bomb that **killed** the US ambassador to Libya was terrorist-inspired.
>    and
>    ***The*** bomb that exploded in Benghazi, **killing** the US ambassador to Libya, was terrorist-inspired.

Comment: Indeed. It seems like: "...killed 7 and wounded 9" would have been a better construct, to the point where I wonder if the paper has some kind of policy against ending a headline with a digit.

Comment: @J.R.: If that were the case, surely "...7 killed and 9 wounded" would be acceptable. It's the mixing of the two modes that gets up my nose, regardless of which way round it's written.

Comment: Good point. Well, at least we both agree it's awful. 8^\

Comment: In your second and third examples the *-ed* forms are  past-tense verbs, not past participles.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't *think* I said otherwise (well, I didn't mean to, anyway). My point is that *"Bomb in Magallanes: 7 killed, 9 wounded"*, say, is a perfectly credible headline, under which the more "grammatical" article text might refer to Dr XYZ, *"...who treated 4 **wounded**"* (which definitely looks like a *noun* to me). OP's headline could have reasonably ended with *"...7 **dead** and 9 wounded"*, but actually it's more akin to *"...dead 7 and 9 wounded"*. Which just looks like a weird conjunction of disparate forms to me.